# Delete references to files on nodes without saving the node

Tags: entities, ajax, media

I have an image field (unlimited values) with his default button "delete", when i click it the image disappear but, as Drupal works, it will not be actually deleted from the node until the node is saved. If I reload the page without saving, the images are still there.

How can I save the node at the image delete? I was thinking about using `hook_form_alter()` but this is an ajax request done by the "delete" button so it's a different matter.

If I catch the right hook and save the node in ajax, could this create problems?

I only find info about how to delete images physically from the folders after they have been removed from the node.

Comment: I'm not going to say not do it, as I see your point.  But I think that would be bad user experience.  As a user, I should be able to remove, add, preview and change all before making my FINAL save.  It helps keep the user out of trouble.  Maybe add a message instead that says, make sure to save your form, or nothing is final until you save.  Just like on the table drag.  "* The changes to this form will not be saved until the Save button is clicked."  Just a thought.

Comment: I think saving the node while you habe the node form open might cause a problem. You will not be able to save the node anymore from the form since the content was altered somewhere else and the state the node is in as the form "sees" it is different from the actual state. If you really want to try it this way you could try it with field_attach_update.